# What is the character limit for sending an Ardor message to another account?

Tags: ardor, message

I'm sending a message on the Ardor blockchain to another account, but what is the message character limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character limit for a non-prunable message is 160 characters, but if its prunable it is max 42K.

Find the api parameter:
messageIsPrunable=true